# iOS Delay between touchstart and touchmove?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, ios, touch

I'm attempting to convert my web app into a form usable by mobile devices.  I'm attempting to build in support for touch gestures like horizontal scrolling. I'm finding some strange behavior in my app.

I start a gesture with a touchstart event, and then scroll on touchmove.  However, my application sees a 500-700 ms delay between receiving these two events. As far as I can tell, my app is doing no other work between these two events.

Other aspects:
The code is written in jquery, using

```
  $(element).bind(touchmove, function(ev) {return myobject.DoTouch(ev) }
```

were the DoTouch command  simply checks the ev.type, records the touch position, and returns false.

Any ideas what I should look for to try to solve this? The lag between touching and getting a response from the app is very annoying.

Comment: Are you only testing it via the iOS Simulator? I'm pretty sure it intentionally adds delay.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  It turns out, this is how iOS works.  I was pulling my own hair out for some time.  Read more here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html.  Essentially, if iOS thinks it can handle this as an internal PAN gesture, it does and doesn't even bother sending a `touchmove` event at all.

In my project, I found that if the viewer makes the touchmove gesture very deliberately and pauses a bit longer before lifting the finger at the end of the move, then the `touchmove` event is, in fact, sent as one might expect.  So, the documented behaviour may be a little iffy versus reality, which only added to confusion and my debugging efforts.

Anyway, if iOS handles the event internally as a PAN gesture, it will send a `scroll` event before the `touchend`.  In my project I was able to use this to set the flag I was using to distinguish dragging gestures (which was normally sent in my touchmove handler) and ignore any behaviour in stand-alone touchend handlers that were not related to the handling of my own scroll-handling.

I hope this helps you (and others) as well!